# How to send data from Intent Service back to Activity and continue executing?

Tags: android, android-intent

In MainActivity I created an intent and used `putExtra()` method to pass data to my Intent Service. In my Intent Service I create HTTP request and get the response, I want to pass the response back to MainActivity.

**MainActivity** code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] a0 = {"first","second"};
        int[] a1 = {1,2,3};
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackGround.class);
        intent.putExtra("a0",a0);
        intent.putExtra("a1",a1);
        intent.putExtra("numberOfArguments",2);
        intent.putExtra("fileName","program.java");
        startService(intent);
        /* i want to continue the program here after getting
        the response and do some stuff*/

    }
}
```

**IntentService** code:

```
public class BackGround extends IntentService {


    final static String NAME = "BackGround";
    public BackGround(String name) {
        super(NAME);

    }
    public  BackGround(){
        super(NAME);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://68d1e2eb.ngrok.io")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        ServerJsonObject serverJsonObject = new ServerJsonObject(bundle.getString("fileName"),
                new NestedObject(bundle.getStringArray("a0"),bundle.getIntArray("a1")),bundle.getInt("numberOfArguments"));
        Call<Result> call = api.sendData(serverJsonObject);
        try {
            Response<Result> response = call.execute();
            // i want to return Result to main activity
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

How to do this in my case?

Comment: `Retrofit` calls are already asynchronous you do not need an `IntentService` to do that. Why making things complicated?

Comment: First you should not use intent service for this because it is not meant for this use volley retrofit or any http method off main thread. But if u still want to use u can use ResultReceiver to get data back from Intent service to Activity.

Comment: @ِADM i want to do it in synchronous way (blocking).

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: `RetroFit` call can also run synchronous way ,. Well if you want synchronous then why did you used `IntentService` at first place? I think you messed up with the Use case of `Service` .

Comment: @ADM i understood that UI thread can't have synchronous requests, that's why i used `IntentService` .

Comment: Use interface to communicate!

Comment: I think you really no need an service to make http request. Simply use `AsyncTask` and pass result back to activity using `interface`

Answer (score 0):

put Handler in your activity like

```
Handler mHandler=new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and pass message to handler from service.

```
  if (mHandler != null) {
        Message m = new Message();
        m.obj = "completed";
        mHandler.sendMessage(m);
    }
```